# Facebook Debugger Tool Showing og:type: profile instead of og:type: musician

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have used the Open Graph tags to classify people.

For example, Elvis is of course a musician:

http://www.famousbirthdays.com/people/elvis-presley.html

```
<meta property="og:type" content="musician"/>
```

However, when I run the Facebook object debugger - here is what it says under type

```
og:type:    profile
```

any reason why it is saying profile as opposed to musician under the type on the object debugger?

Answer (score 2):

A musician is a person, and a person has a profile. So the debugger is stating that yes, this is a musician but that musician is really a data type: profile.

og:type's are limited by verticals if you do not provide your own namespace (this is what the CURIE is for). See http://ogp.me/#types

> music:musician - profile - The musician that made this song.

Remember, in an open graph everything is supposed to link to something else. Only a few cases are attributes non-linking.